# how to call speak method multiple times

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to call the `speak` method of class `TextToSpeech` multiple times, but it does not seem to work - it only speaks the last phrase each time.

```
String temp="ABCD";        
ss(temp);         
String temp1="WXYZ";         
ss(temp1);         
public void ss(String t){        
    tts.speak(t, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);      
}
```

`tts` is an object of class `TexttoSpeech` method.

Comment: Maybe it starts to speak `temp`, and you instantly tell it to speak `temp1`, and it begins to speak `temp1` without finishing speaking `temp`? If so, add a delay between the calls using [Thread.sleep(ms)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html);

Answer (score 0):

your question does not explains if multiple time is simultany or every time 5 seconds for example, however you can try:

```html
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ss("string text");
                }
            });
            thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
tts.speak(t, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

...to...

```
tts.speak(t, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

FLUSH always stops speaking whatever is being spoken and clears the buffer. ADD will add the new text to the queue.